# Dynamic images via PHP and BLOB in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, internet-explorer, blob

I have written a php script that grabs an icon from MySQL dynamically depending on which page you are on.

It works perfectly in Safari, but only shows the alt tag in Firefox and Explorer.

Any help on this welcome as now a little stuck!

Code to pull in image:

```
echo '<img src="WEBSITE/_scripts/showIcon.php?appId='.$_GET['appId'].'" alt="icon" />';
```

ShowIcon.php page:

```
<?php
require(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)). '/db.inc.php');

mysql_select_db($CONNECTION, $TABLE);
$appIcon = mysql_query("SELECT image_app FROM CC_apps WHERE id_app = '1' LIMIT 1", $TABLE) or die(mysql_error());
$ri = mysql_fetch_assoc($appIcon);

$imagebytes = $ri['image_app'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $imagebytes; 
?>
```

I have used this script before, (well very similar) and works fine on all browsers...

Comment: Look into the image and check whether there are any PHP messages in it. Also, a link to an example image would be helpful

Comment: Are you sure that all images are in JPEG format?

Comment: I am using similar script in my project. Only difference is I am using echo instead of print to send the image. It works fine for me

Comment: What if you add `print "data:image/png;base64,".$imagebytes;` ?

Answer (score 0):

So all it needed was to re-upload the images to the database, and change the type to image/png, and bobs your uncle!

Thanks everyone for the comments.